# Accessing network share through a debian OS

Tags: linux, unix, svn, backup

I am trying to move the SVN backup files from the local directory to a NAS device via Putty and I am using the following syntax, however I am receiving the below error message -

```
debian@debianvm:~/svn-backups$ smbclient //IP/Volume_1/NAS/SVN_backups/ -U 'username' 'password'
Domain=[DLINK-88F0C6] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.2.8]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

Could you please let me know what might be the root cause?

Answer (score 2):

You must provide a share name to smbclient; a subdirectory is not supported.

`smbclient //IP/Volume_1 -U username password`

You should be able to verify this by mounting the share somewhere:

`mount -t cifs //IP/volume_1 /mnt/tmp -o user=username,pass=password`

Comment: Giving a password on the command line is considered bad practice for security resaons: unprivileged users could potentially read the password from the output of `ps` or by checking the relevant parts of the `/proc` filesystem. In the case of `smbclient` you can use the -A/--authentication-file option instead, if mounting filesystems use the `credentials` mount option.

Comment: And ? THat's what he did - I merely assist in troubleshooting.

Comment: @adaptr: just adding potentially relevant information, I wasn't suggesting your answer was wrong. I nearly added the comment to the question instead but felt it made more sense here as the question didn't mention `mount` and you has added that (useful) detail.

Comment: I can mount a subdirectory (on Debian squeeze) using `mount -t cifs '\\cifs.cs.brown.edu\home\jon-test' /mnt/ -o user=jon-test` without problems. Also, @DavidSpillett , it conveniently asks me for my password without additional options :)

Comment: @jon: that is the way I usually do things from the command line. The `credentials` mount option is useful for anything that needs to perform automated mounting where no user will be present to hand over credentials via the keyboard (or where you've given users access to control certain mounts via `sudo` or similar but don't want them to have the actual credentials directly). Both options keep the password away from where it can be easilt read from the process list.

Comment: @DavidSpillett: That makes sense; good to know. Thanks.